# Generating perfect random gaussian numbers

Tags: python, random, numpy, matplotlib, normal-distribution

I tried to generate the series of random numbers with gaussian distribution. So, I used numpy.random.normal(mean,standard deviation,size). However, when I converted these numbers into probabability density function using numpy.histogram, this was not same as Gaussian distribution with same mean and standard deviation made by matplotlib.mlab.normpdf.

I understand it may be because numpy.random.normal is random sampling. So, the PDF of these numbers can't be perfectly Gaussian.

Would you please give any advice about how to get the series of random numbers with mean and standard deviation which would have a Gaussian PDF, if it is possible?
The size of the numbers which I tried to get is 660.

I will really appreciate any advice and help.

Best regards,

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could "z-score" the sample, by subtracting the sample mean and then dividing by the sample standard deviation:

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=660)
x = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
```

That will make your vector have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. But that doesn't mean you will have "perfectly gaussian random numbers." I don't think that's really a concept that makes sense.

It would be helpful to know what application you want to use this for, maybe then it would be easier to suggest alternatives.

Comment: My application purpose is to generate the series of randomly distributed numbers with certain mean and certain standard deviation. With these mean and standard deviation, I can plot Gaussiand PDF with matplotlib.mlab.normpdf. Can I convert this Gaussian PDF into the series of numbers, rather than convert numbers into PDF? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I think that my explanation was not sufficient. I would like to compare the probability density function of one wind velocity time series which I have and Gaussian PDF. Before comparing between these two PDFs, I would like to compare original time series and the series of Gaussian distributed numbers with the standard deviation and mean from original wind velocity series. So, my concern is how to generate these numbers. For my purpose, the generated numbers should have normal distribution PDF. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to draw a [qqplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot)?

Comment: Hi mwaskom, Q-Q plot is a very good point and an idea. However, my goal is much simpler. Just show the fluctuation of original number and Gaussian distributed numbers in the same figure. Generating the series of numbers is not that difficult with numpy.random.normal. The point is that I want that theses generated numbers have PDF matched with Gaussian PDF of same mean and standard deviation. Thank you.